# Ряд Фибоначчи, уменьшение кода и перенес переменных в условие

Tags: c#, циклы, while, числа-фибоначчи

Всем Привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста как компактно переписать код который по индексу выводи число Фиббоначчи.

Вопрос в следующем переменные previousFibonacciNumber, currentFibonacciNumber объявлены рано, т.к. не используются в первом if.
Если сработает первый if, эти переменные окажутся не нужны.
Поэтому нужно объявить их в той ветке, где они используются.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно компактно переделать?

```
        Console.Write("Введите целое число для вычисления числа Фибоначчи с этим индексом (индекс ряда начинается с 0) = ");
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int previousFibonacciNumber = 0;
        int currentFibonacciNumber = 1;

        if (index == 0 || index == 1)
        {
            currentFibonacciNumber = index;
        }
        else 
        {
            int i = 1;

            while (i < index)
            {
                int penultimateFibonacciNumber = previousFibonacciNumber;
                previousFibonacciNumber = currentFibonacciNumber;
                currentFibonacciNumber += penultimateFibonacciNumber;
                i++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Число Фибоначчи с индексом {0} = {1}", index, currentFibonacciNumber);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int currentFibonacciNumber = 1;

    if (index == 0 || index == 1)
    {
        currentFibonacciNumber = index;
    }
    else 
    {
        int previousFibonacciNumber = 0;
        int i = 1;

        while (i < index)
        {
            int penultimateFibonacciNumber = previousFibonacciNumber;
            previousFibonacciNumber = currentFibonacciNumber;
            currentFibonacciNumber += penultimateFibonacciNumber;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, можно ли как то и currentFibonacciNumber, перенести в условие?

Comment: @IgorM Нет. Эта переменная используется в блоке `if` и в `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, а как то может быть можно перестроить код чтобы можно было currentFibonacciNumber. Преподаватель сказал что как то можно previousFibonacciNumber, currentFibonacciNumber перенести в условие?? Сам голову уже сломал...

Comment: @IgorM если перенести переменную внутрь `if` это сделает её *невидимой* за пределами блока оператора `if`. может быть Вы не правильно поняли своего преподавателя(или это проверка ваших знаний и преподаватель ожидает услышать обоснование почему `currentFibonacciNumber` не может быть объявлена иначе)

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение! очень благодарен Вам!